# Hortonwork Ambari services not started

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am using Hortonwork sandbox using Virtual box. I am not able to start Ambari services like Hive, Spark, etc. I am going through below steps :

1. http://localhost:1080
2. Advanced HDP quicklink
3. http://localhost:4200/ ->  `root /hadoop`
4. Ambari (http://localhost:8080/) -> Not able to start services here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please start the following service manually in the mentioned order.

```
1. Zookeeper 
2. HDFS 
3. YARN 
4. MapReduce 
5. HIVE 
6. Spark
```

Another thing, I've also used HDP Sandbox and default user with administration-level access is "raj_ops", and default credentials of this user is

```
Username: raj_ops
Password: raj_ops
```

Please told me is this useful or not?